# A question about Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $h $ be Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$.Let $a\in [c,d]$ and $g(x)=\int_a^x h(t)dt $. Suppose $f $ is Riemann integrable on $g([c,d])$
How do you show the integral $\int_c^df(g(x))h(x)dx$ exists and is equal to  $\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(x)dx  $ ?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried for this?  This type of problem is reasonably standard and, as far as I can tell, should be provable directly from the definition of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral (the former quantity being $\int_c^d f(g(x))dg(x)$).  As a hint, the fact that $h(t)$ is properly Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$ shows you that $g(x)$ is a function of bounded variation.

Comment: Simply prove that $g'(x) = h(x)$, which has probably been proved in your book or class, and then this is the change of variables theorem. To prove the change of variables theorem, you could for instance use the chain rule to differentiate $F(g(x))$, where $F$ is a primitive of $f$.

Comment: @Pedro $h(x)$ is not given to be continuous, so that is only true $a.e.$.

Comment: thanks @Chris , I've forgoten something about iemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: @Chris, this problem is not as easy as your hint. I find a paper . http://www.jstor.org/pss/3614764

Comment: I am very surprised to find that this result is so difficult, sorry.  I didn't think it would require the Lebesgue characterization of Riemann integrable functions.

Answer (score -1):

With a substitution. Let $y=g(x)$. Then $dy=g'(x) dx= h(x) dx$ where we have used the fundamental theorem of calculus. Thus

$\int_c^df(g(x))h(x)dx =\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(y)dy$

and you are done.

Comment: sorry,$g$ need not be differentiable.

Comment: Please read Rudin's Real & Complex Chapter 8. g will have a derivative a.e. in the classical sense. This is rather tricky to prove.

Comment: But I need a elementary proof. And the theorem you give does not seems slove my problem.

Comment: It clearly DOES solve your problem! Look at the proof first and then decide. There might not be a more elementary proof...what leads you to think there is one?

Comment: Nik, you mean if y=g'(x) a.e, then $\int_{c}^{d}f(g(x))g'(x)dx  = \int_{g(c)}^{g(d)} f(x)dx $ ? Generally, that is incorect.

Comment: Nik, this is a problem about Riemann integrals, not Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: @Nik , Chris shows me a right direction.